# Are there any special settings I need to do for running automation test on Windows 10 edge

Tags: c#, jquery, windows, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

Are there any special settings I need to do for running automation test on Windows 10 edge. Eg: enabling Enhanced protected mode etc..

On Windows 7 IE11 typing was slower so I enabled Enhanced protected mode and test running fine. but the same test not able to find elements on edge browser, just opening the site. I am using Jquery selectors to find the elements.

Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a WebDriver for Windows Edge was released. You can read further [here](http://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/07/23/bringing-automated-testing-to-microsoft-edge-through-webdriver/).

You can check out [here](https://dev.modern.ie/platform/status/webdriver/details/) what is supported already and what they still need to implement, so hopefully it will be of use to you.